# Tracing nuisance or malicious cellphone calls

Tags: phone

Is it possible for an ordinary citizen to trace source of nuisance calls to cell phone when caller ID has been blocked?

Comment: It might not be possible without your service provider help

Comment: @AliAhmad Agreed. With a blocked number, it's the job of the phone company and police. With an unblocked number, you are still left with the possibility of a spoofed number.

Comment: Somewhat related reading (not a duplicate of) with some good answers: [How to trace a (mobile) phone?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/12659/20074). ;)

Comment: What if... what if the calls are coming from inside the house?! :((((

Answer (score 5):

The caller ID you get is what your provider tell you and in turn it's what the caller's provider claims. Even your service provider cannot trace the exact source of the call, it only knows what the caller's provider claims.

So you need the cooperation of your provider to give information about the call (mainly the caller's provider). Then you need the cooperation of the caller's provider and you give them your number and the time of call, then it could be possible for them to identify the caller.

The whole process is nearly impossible for the normal Joe to do. You need help from the authorities. Even then, don't really count on them. Depending on your jurisdiction, unless your caller is a "terrorist" or some high-profile criminal, they likely won't do anything.

Comment: Insert "depends on jurisdiction" here ... Some police forces can take this sort of thing seriously.

Comment: @schroeder in what jurisdiction does receiving a call with a blocked caller ID constitutes a serious matter? shouldn't the authorities in those jurisdiction pursue VoIP-to-PSTN services like Skype then? I'm really interested to know. (disregarding kidnapping or death threat cases, of course). Because as far as I know, many international calls don't have deliver the caller ID, do the authorities take this matter seriously also? Unless it's a serious matter, I can assure (with high confidence) that no police force would take this matter seriously just to satisfy the call receiver's curiosity.

Comment: "this sort of thing" = "nuisance and malicious calls" as mentioned by the OP. Some jurisdictions do take those kinds of calls seriously regardless of blocked ids. If you meant your "they won't do anything" comment in regards to simply tracking down a caller, you might need to clarify that.