# How does phone tracking by police work?

Tags: android, phone, smartphone, user-tracking, tracking

For android phones in India

1. can police get a phone's IMEI number just by using that phone's number?
2. also suppose if a phone was moving around within few miles radius for few days and it was turned on several times in that duration. **But now the phone is turned off permanently and only after phone is turned off police starts to try to track the phone for the first time** using only the mobile number which was being used by that phone when it was turned on in last few days. So can police get all the locations where that phone was in those last few days?
3. Also if that phone's user **turns off permanently or throws away the phone** and takes a new phone and inserts the same SIM card in that new phone, and **only after that if police starts to try to track using that mobile no for the first time,** can police even get all the location infos about where that old phone was for last few days before it was thrown away?

Comment: From the technical perspective: the mobile phone provider knows the approximate location of a phone connected to the mobile network since it is connected to one or several cell towers. It can also be associated with a specific identity using the SIM. As for the conditions in which the police gets access to this information - this is a purely legal question so please check at [law.se].

Comment: Tyvm for replying. But if that phone's user throws away the phone and take a new phone and inserts the same sim card in that new phone, and after that if police starts to try to track using that mobile no for first time, can police even get all the location infos about where that old phone were for last few days before it was thrown away?

Comment: A phone can only be tracked if it is connected to something, i.e. typically a cell tower but maybe also a WiFi network etc. If the phone is completely off (as in: battery down, not just screen switched off) it cannot be tracked.

Comment: Tyvm again. but the phone was turned on with that sim for few days. after that the phone was turned off permanently and the sim was removed. but police started tracking the phone only after the phone got turned off permanently. So, can now police get all the history of locations the phone was in for last few days when it was turned on?

Comment: The real question here is if the local cell providers keep past location history for phones that are not currently connected.  It doesn't matter if the phone is on or off or destroyed to get historical data.

Comment: The mobile service provider keep some history, as required by their needs and as required by the local law. Policy might get access to this information in some conditions. What are the specific conditions and how long the mobile service provider is required to keep the data -> legal question, off-topic here and on-topic at [law.se].

Comment: Tyvm All. Wish i could know in India, network providers how long retain location infos of a cell phone user and what the police are allowed to ask to network providers!

Comment: That's a legal question, out of scope here.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich all that really needs to be made an answer, not comments

Comment: @schroeder: It wasn't clear to me if the question is about the (off-topic) legal aspects (how long data are stored, how can policy access it) or about the technical aspects (do the necessary data exist at all). Right now the question looks primarily off-topic to me and on-topic on [law.se]. As for the non-legal stuff this might be covered by questions like [How to trace a (mobile) phone?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12659/how-to-trace-a-mobile-phone) which explains how tracing works.